# Отобразить все окна в винде

Tags: windows, windows-7, окно

Пару раз что-то случайно нажимал и на рабочем столе отображались все открытые окна рядом(как в убунте), но маленькие. При клике по любому месту они возвращались к первоначальному состоянию.

Это НЕ Win+TabЭто не один из этих режимов: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Manage-multiple-windows

Это именно мои окошки, только сильно уменьшенные и, как бы растащенные по десктопу огромного разрешения.Как этого же достичь?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Это одна из кнопок мыши так себя ведет - логитеховский переключатель приложений.

Answer (score 1):

Win+Tab это именно винтабя извиняюсь, но даже по [ссылке в вопросе](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/products/windows) написано:

> To switch windows using Flip 3D press the Windows logo key  +Tab to open Flip 3D.

Comment: Не. Винтаб показывает их чуток развернутыми, в карусели. А тут они были рядом, почти как в восьмерке.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно!Win+Tab![alt tab][1]а можно так:Alt+Tab![alt tab][2][1]:http://i.imgur.com/SUL9r.png[2]:http://i.imgur.com/uF6Ay.png

Answer (score 0):

может быть Win-Space?

Comment: причем тут скрытие окон?

Answer (score 0):

Может, отведён курсор на кнопку "свернуть все окна"?И вообще, нельзя ли следить за тем, что нажимаете?И ещё, может вопрос показаться немного наивным, но это не мог быть "Alt-Tab"?